# Angular 2+ Component Library - packaging assets

Tags: angular, shared-libraries

I have created a Angular 4 based component library. I have also been able to successfully use this library in another Angular project. However, one of the components makes use of a SVG, which is located in the `/assets` folder of the library. This is being referred in the component as follows,

```
<img src="/assets/svg/icon_recommendation_close.svg"/>
```

Obviously, when this component is used the main app, the image is looked for in the /assets folder of the main app, which is not available resulting in HTTP 404.

Now my questions are,

1. What are the options available to me to package images and other
   similar assets?
2. How can these be made available to the main app?
3. Is it possible to configure the main app to look into the `/nodes_module`
   folder of the library if I am able to package the SVG into it?
4. The other option I was thinking was to inline the SVG into the HTML itself using a `gulp` utility. Is it ok to do this?

Thanks 
Sushil

Comment: This is a package building issue and there are to many ways to package a library. As you say, gulg, grunt, make, webpack, etc.. etc.. The question needs to be more specific.

Comment: Hi Sushil did you found a solution?